# TestComplete 8 and IE 9: handling two processes

Tags: internet-explorer-9, testcomplete

Launching IE9 with a URL I find two processes are started; a parent and child process. In TestComplete's ObjectBrowser both processes have a Page node, and the related children.

In my Silverlight AUT(Application under test) there is a datagrid, that I need to scroll.
I check for the scrollbar before attempting to scroll the grid.

However I get different results depending on the process I use.

```
aqObject.IsSupported(
    Sys.Process("iexplore", 1).Page("https://localhost/url/" ).Panel("silverlightContainer" ).Object(0 ).UIAObject("Popup" ).UIAObject("x" ).UIAObject("tab" ).UIAObject("TabItem", 2 ).UIAObject("StepList" )
, "VerticalScrollPercent")

aqObject.IsSupported(
    Sys.Process("iexplore", 2).Page("https://localhost/url/" ).Panel("silverlightContainer" ).Object(0 ).UIAObject("Popup" ).UIAObject("x" ).UIAObject("tab" ).UIAObject("TabItem", 2 ).UIAObject("StepList" )
, "VerticalScrollPercent")
```

One of these will return true, the other false. It doesn't seem to matter how much I refresh the world `Sys.Refresh` or the control `Sys.Process...UIAObject("StepList").Refresh`, one will always fail while the other passes.

This is really odd, but I could work around it if it was predictable, but it isn't. Sometimes the parent process tree works, sometimes the child.

My question is..

- What is going on?
- How do I decide at the point of launching the app
  which process to use for automation?
- How else could I achieve my goal of scrolling the list (so I can find the row I want) without experiencing this problem?

Comment: Wow this question has been viewed 1000 times ... but no upvotes! Not sure what that says about the quality of the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because of Internet Explorer's **LCIE** feature (Loosely-Coupled Internet Explorer). It makes Internet Explorer to have a main process and a separate process for every opened web page. You can find more information on this feature along with details on how to disable it in the [Preparing Internet Explorer for Web Testing](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/30382/) help topic.

Also, you can upgrade you instance of the tool to TestComplete 9. This version allows accessing a page object regardless of the type of a browser and index of its instance. For example:

```
var page = Sys.Browser().Page("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I'm using IE9. I already tried setting the TabProcGrowth property, but it didn't have any effect... isn't this just for IE8?

Comment: This should work for IE9 as well. Are you sure that two IEXPLORE processes exist (in Object Browser or Task Manager) if you see a single Internet Explorer window even after you applied the TabProcGrowth property?